# "Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr" error in a multicolumn table

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I got this error:

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> \endtemplate 

l.41 &
      \multicolumn{3}{l}{\bf Head of Department }   \\
```

When I attempted to compile my code. A snippet follows:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
%
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\bf Seminar Guide/Supervisor}
&\multicolumn{3}{l}{\bf Seminar Coordinator}      
&\multicolumn{3}{l}{\bf Head of Department }   \\
%
     &     &      &    \\
%
Name: &     & Name: &  \\
\multicolumn{3}{l}{Mr. Aadars M S}%    
&\multicolumn{3}{l}{Mis. Anjaly S Kumar}%   
&\multicolumn{3}{l}{Prof. Rajendran T.K }   \\ %
 \multicolumn{3}{l}{M.Tech, MISTE } %
 \multicolumn{3}{l}{M.Tech, MISTE } %
&\multicolumn{3}{l}{ME, FITE} \\%
%
    &    &    &    \\
%
Signature&: .............................
\qquad\quad   & 
Signature&: .............................
\qquad\quad   & 
Signature&: .............................\\
%
    &    &    &    \\
%
%
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Your problem is that you need to end the line in lines 39 and 40, so it should be `\multicolumn{3}{l}{\bf Seminar Guide/Supervisor} \\ ` etc. As it stands, you have `\begin{tabular}{llll}` which specifies a table with four columns. But then you have three `\multicolumn{3}`s so that's 9 columns. But you've asked for a table with four columns

Comment: P.S. in general it's better to include a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). The gold standard is that everything should be there, i should be able to copy and paste all your code and run it immediately and see on my screen exactly what you see on yours without having to do anything else. But, no extra information should be there, nothing that isn't necessary to show the error. If in doubt, it's better to include too much rather than too little

Comment: Welcome! Although the `\multicolumn`s seem egregious here. In any case, `\bf` is 20+ years obsolete and ought not be used in LaTeX documents.

Comment: i want three colums

Comment: This question is duplicated at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301692/i-need-to-make-the-certificate-page-in-latex-as-follows-plz-help-me-find-an-ans.

Comment: If you want 3 columns, remove the `\multicolumn`s. If you really want 3 rather than 4, change `llll` to `lll`. Right now, you have far more than 4 columns, so remember to make sure you specify enough for the content you want to create.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your typesetting objectives correctly, you don't need *any* of the `\multicolumn` instructions. Instead, something like the following should do just fine:

```
...
\begin{tabular}{lll}
  \bfseries Seminar Guide/Supervisor
& \bfseries Seminar Coordinator
& \bfseries Head of Department \\[1ex]
  Mr.\ Aadars M S   
& Mis.\ Anjaly S Kumar 
& Prof.\ Rajendran T.K.   \\
  M.Tech, MISTE 
& M.Tech, MISTE
& ME, FITE \\[1ex]
Signature: ............................... &
Signature: .................... &
Signature: ....................\\
\end{tabular}
...
```